# How do I divide the hours provided by each staff for one service user in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

- The Client is being provided a service by Carers and one client can have 2, 3, 4 or 5 etc Carers for 1 hrs, 2 hrs etc.
- Assume 4 Carers provides a service to Mr Smith (Client A; Service Type: 1:4)
- They all start at 9am and finish at 10:30am for 16/11/18
- The total hours they provide to the Client is 1 hr 30 mins
- I need to divide the hours into 4 so in the table it would show 4 rows for Mr Smith and the hours provided would be: 1 hr 30mins divided by 4 Careers
- This would result to 0.38 minutes for each Career under Mr Smith at 9am to 10:30am for the 16/11/18

See the below query which does not work and see the desired results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      LEFT(Service_ID,CHARINDEX(' ',Service_ID + ' ') -1) AS Client_ID
     ,RIGHT(Service_Name,LEN(Service_Name)-CHARINDEX(' ', Service_Name)) AS Client_Name
     ,SS.SHIFT_TYPE_NAME as ShiftType
     ,CONVERT(CHAR(10),SS.START_DATE, 103) AS Subshift_Start_Date
     ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),SS.START_DATE,108) AS Subshift_Start_Time
     ,CONVERT(CHAR(10),SS.END_DATE, 103) AS Subshift_End_Date
     ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),SS.END_DATE,108) AS Subshift_End_Time
     ,SP2.SHIFT_PROPERTY_CODE AS Service_Type
     ,ORG.ORG_NAME as Area   
     ,CONCAT((DATEDIFF(Minute,SS.START_DATE,SS.END_DATE)/60),':'
     ,(DATEDIFF(Minute,SS.START_DATE,SS.END_DATE)%60))  AS Shift_Hours 

FROM  tbl_Subshift SS LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_EMPLOYEE EE 
      ON SS.EMPLOYEE_ID = EE.EMPLOYEE_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_EMPLOYEE_REVISION ER 
      ON ER.EMPLOYEE_ID = EE.EMPLOYEE_ID .....

WHERE   SS.SHIFT_TYPE_NAME IN ('Non Leave', 'Sleepover', 'Waking Night')
         AND Substring(Service_Name,1,3) = 'CS-' or Substring(Service_Name,1,4) = 'CS -'
         AND SP2.SHIFT_PROPERTY_CODE NOT IN ('Shadow Shift')       
         AND SS.START_DATE >= '2019-10-14 00:00:00.000' 
         AND SS.START_DATE <='2019-11-10 00:00:00.000'

ORDER BY Service_ID, Subshift_Start_Date, Subshift_Start_Time  DESC
```

The Desired Result should be

```
Service_ID  Service_Name   ShiftType    Subshift_Start_Date Subshift_Start_Time Subshift_End_Date   Subshift_End_Time   Service_Type    Area    Shift_Hours Shift_Split_Hours       
S1          Mr A Smith     Non Leave    16/11/2018          09:00   16/11/2018  10:30   1:4 Support North Lanarkshire   01:30   0.38    in time format  38 minutes
S1          Mr A Smith     Non Leave    16/11/2018          09:00   16/11/2018  10:30   1:4 Support North Lanarkshire   01:30   0.38    in time format  38 minutes
S1          Mr A Smith     Non Leave    16/11/2018          09:00   16/11/2018  10:30   1:4 Support North Lanarkshire   01:30   0.38    in time format  38 minutes
S1          Mr A Smith     Non Leave    16/11/2018          09:00   16/11/2018  10:30   1:4 Support North Lanarkshire   01:30   0.38    in time format  38 minutes

S2          Mrs B Gary     Non Leave    01/07/2019          09:30   01/07/2019  15:00   1:2 Support East Lothian    05:30   3.15    in time format  3hrs 15mins
S2          Mrs B Gary     Non Leave    01/07/2019          09:30   01/07/2019  15:00   1:2 Support East Lothian    05:30   3.15    in time format  3hrs 15mins
```

Comment: Please post sample input and output data

Comment: You put the result in - that's good. Now please put some example input data in.

Comment: Hi there This is the example input data

Comment: I see output data. I don't see input data

Comment: Hi there when i run the query the result is above apart from the Shift split hours which is blank is the input data.

Comment: OK I think I understand now. You need 90 divided by 4 = 22.5 minutes = .38 of an hour. Since you haven't provided input data (`tbl_Subshift`, `tbl_EMPLOYEE` etc. and sample data), you need to edit your query and _Alias_ every column so we can have some kind of idea of which table the column is coming from. The solution is straightforward. You need to pre-count that carers per service id, then join to that and divide by it.

Comment: So basically you add another table to your table list. The table looks _something_ like this: `(SELECT Service_ID, COUNT(*) As CarerCount FROM tbl_Subshift GROUP BY Service_ID) AS CarersPerService` then you join to that on `Service_ID`. That returns a _4_ against S1 and you divide the minutes by that